# Как поменять значение строки app.videoId"" по нажатию кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin

В общем суть проблемы такова. Есть две Активити в первой кнопки, а во второй плеер, при нажатии на кнопку идёт переход на вторую активити и показывает видео, а при нажатии на другую кнопку должно показывать другое видео(вот это как раз и не получается)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".YouTube1Activity3">


    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:videoId="lSTo5hKT55I"
        app:autoPlay="true"
        app:showYouTubeButton="false"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Конечно если код запускается в таком виде с вписанным videoId""то видео запускается и будет всегда одно!
В общем как прописать чтоб при нажатии разных кнопок менялся линк на видео в строке app:videoId""
вот код активити с кнопками

```
 class YouTubeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube)


    }
    fun button5(view: View) {
        val button5 = Intent(this, YouTube1Activity3::class.java)
        startActivity(button5)
        



    }
    fun button6(view: View) {
        val button6 = Intent(this, YouTube1Activity3::class.java)
        startActivity(button6)




    }
}
```

И главное ребята я новичок в котлине так что если что объясните подробнее либо отправте где почитать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно передавать `video_id` в `YouTube1Activity3`.

А в `YouTube1Activity3` вы должны уже сами достать `video_id` из `intent` по ключу `VIDEO_ID` и установить этот айди в `YouTubePlayerView`.

Примерно так должен выглядеть код, обратите внимание на стиль. Я убрал лишние строки и добавил отступы между функциями.

Переименуйте названия функций и классов, я не стал этого делать, чтоб вы не запутались.
Например вместо `button5` можно `onButton5Click`.
А вместо `YouTube1Activity3`  можно `YouTubePlayerActivity`.
Приучитесь сразу функциям и классам давать осмысленные названия на английском языке.

```
class YouTubeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_layout)
    }

    fun button5(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, YouTubeActivity::class.java)
        intent.extras?.putString(VIDEO_ID, "id_5") // Передаем videoId в YouTubeActivity3. Подставить свой videoId вместо id_5
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun button6(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this, YouTubeActivity::class.java)
        intent.extras?.putString(VIDEO_ID, "id_6") // Передаем videoId в YouTubeActivity3. Подставить свой videoId вместо id_6
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    /**
     * Тоже самое что и вверху, но уже с плюшками котлина
     * Дублирующийся код вынесен в общую функцию
     * Вижу, что вы только в самом начале, и вот показываю возможности языка

    fun button5(view: View) = startYoutube3("id_5") // Подставить свой videoId вместо id_5

    fun button6(view: View) = startYoutube3("id_6") // Подставить свой videoId вместо id_6

    private fun startYoutube3(videoId: String) =
        Intent(this, YouTubeActivity::class.java).apply {
            extras?.putString(VIDEO_ID, videoId) // Передаем videoId в YouTubeActivity3
        }.let(::startActivity)
     */

    companion object {
        const val VIDEO_ID = "youtube_video_id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал оба кода не меняет параметр videoId, как я понял в строку app.videoId="" я должен вписать "youtube_video_id" всякое пробовал но нет не меняет если вписать не id то просто пишет нет видео Video unavailable

Comment: Я показал лишь как передать строку в другую активити.
Вы должны достать эту строку из extras и установить в YouTubePlayerView